# How to do unit tests in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, oop

I have heard about unit test in VS. Many persons of this community tells that create unit test will improve your OOP designs.

I really have no idea of it. Can you know a web site o example about how to create it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start unit testing or TDD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365943/how-to-start-unit-testing-or-tdd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided you have the correct version of Visual Studio (I believe it's a minimum of *Professional* that includes the ability to Unit Test), you just create a new project (preferably using the **Test** template).  Referencing your code that you want to Unit Test, you write `TestMethod`s that will `Assert()` what you require to be true.

You can also pull up the *Test View*, which will list out all of your Unit Tests so you can Run/Debug them on the fly.

A Unit Test is really just a code library that uses the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` namespace (*Note*: this is for MSTest, which ships with VS.  There are many other Unit Testing tools/libraries out there).

**For further details, please see this MSDN article: [Walkthrough: Creating and Running Unit Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx).**

Answer (score 4):

You definitely do not HAVE to use the Visual Studio test tools. I have heard from various sources that the test engine is slow compared to NUnit.

I'd say NUnit is probably the most-used unit test engine for .Net. xUnit, its successor (by the same team I believe) is also gaining popularity.

Are you asking about unit tests specifically, or about test-driven development? Do you know? Unit tests are a technique - and many including myself would say a vital one. Test-driven development is a philosophy. Therefore the latter is likely to need buy-in from your team.

Comment: +1 for mentioning unit testing is not strictly bound to VS and its frameworks.